# Unable to set ChromeOptions for Selenium Webdriver C#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium chrome driver to open URLs and I am creating  new driver instance for each URL. I am assigning port number for each URL through ChromeOptions.

As I mentioned earlier, I am creating a new port number for each URL. During first iteration port is opened and URL loaded properly but after the first iteration new port is not getting opened. I have verified the port status using `netstat -an` in command prompt. only my first port number is listed there.

So when breakpoint hits this line of code `driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeService, m_Options);` nothing happens for a minute and I am getting timeout error since the port is not available to connect.

```
private static List<int> processIdList = new List<int>();
IWebDriver driver;
foreach (var url in urls)
{

  int portno = GetAvailablePortNumber(); 
  ProcessStartInfo pcsInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
  pcsInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
  pcsInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
  pcsInfo.Arguments =  = "--new-window --remote-debugging-port=portno --disable-fre --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --user-data-dir=C:\\SeleniumApps\\WebLauncherTool\\bin\\Debug\\ChromeUser\\portno"
  
  pcsInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
  Process process = new Process();
  process.StartInfo = pcsInfo;
  
  if (process.Start())
  {
      processId = process.Id;
      processIdList.Add(processId);
  }
    
  ChromeDriverService chromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
  chromeService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
  ChromeOptions m_Options = new ChromeOptions();
  m_Options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
  m_Options.DebuggerAddress = $"localhost:{portno}";
  driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeService, m_Options);
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

}
```

I could not figure out why the port is not getting opened.
Can someone shed some light on this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior when chrome driver session launched is:

1. Chromedriver process launched on *some free port*.
2. Chromedriver process launches chrome-browser process with `--remote-debugging-port=0` which means *some free port*.
3. Chromedriver process interacts with chrome-browser process

**Providing DebuggerAddress**

When we define `DebuggerAddress`, this means:

1. Chromedriver process launched on *some free port*.
2. Chromedriver process **DO NOT LAUNCH** chrome-browser process, but tries connecting by provided `DebuggerAddress`.

**Providing --remote-debugging-port**

When we define `--remote-debugging-port`, this means:

1. Chromedriver process launched on *some free port*.
2. Chromedriver process launches chrome-browser process on port=`--remote-debugging-port`

**Providing Chromedriver service port**

1. Chromedriver process launched on port=*chromedriver service port*.
2. Chromedriver process launches chrome-browser process with `--remote-debugging-port=0` which means *some free port*.
3. Chromedriver process interacts with chrome-browser process

---

So, providing `DebuggerAddress` is required for the case, when we want to connect to already launched with `--remote-debugging-port` browser instance.

Comment: But I need separate port number. Can you please tell me if there is any workaround to achieve the same?

Comment: You might create a script which will accept the port number, and will run the browser from command line and then WebDriver session for it. And during tear-down you'll have to close chrome browser process and quit the driver. Will this match your requirements? If yes, I'll try to elaborate..

Comment: @Ask_SO try to launch the driver without `m_Options.DebuggerAddress = "localhost:33853";`, but add `m_Options.AddArgument($"--remote-debugging-port={portno}");`

Comment: Sure, Definitely it would help.

Comment: I tried like this and for first URL chrome launched with single tab and first URL loaded successfully and during next URL call, new tab opened in existing chrome window and also new separate chrome window opened and in that new window second URL is loaded.. same case for third URL also.

Comment: if I remove m_Options.DebuggerAddress = "localhost:33853"; from my code, 3 tabs are opening but all 3 URLs are loading sequentially in the first tab itself. 2nd and 3rd tabs address bar is blank.

Comment: So, I've evaluated it a little more. Could you, please explain the final behavior you want to achieve. I we are talking about ports, there are 2 different ports. First - chromedriver-service port. Second chrome browser remote debugging port. So we always have a pair of ports per session. And by default, all the ports are random free ports. In your request you're trying also to provide the random debugging port. This port means the port, chromedriver try to connect instead of launching a new chrome browser on some port.

Comment: I've tested launching multiple selenium sessions with some --remote-debugging-port defined and also without defining and always got isolated webdriver sessions without any issues. So I trying to understand your request. Maybe some issue is behind the code example you've provided.

Comment: I'll update my answer with the elaboration results.

Comment: I've updated my question with complete code.  I am launching chrome browser first then chrome driver since I need ProcessID details which is very important for me. Can you please help me on the latest code.

Comment: @Ask_SO I've tried to launch the chrome in a process with your command line args, and then launched chrome-driver, and works. Then I tried to launch 3-4 browsers in a loop and it also works like a charm. But, unfortunately, I'm experimenting not with C#, but with Java. So I can confirm that selenium functionality works perfect. One thing I'm confuced: you've created `IWebDriver driver` behind the loop, but in the loop you always overrite this variable. `driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeService, m_Options);`. That might be the reason why your commands go to some single browser.

Comment: The reason for `driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeService, m_Options);` is to assign with updated port number. Is it possible to launch multiple with `DebuggerAddress = $"localhost:{port}";` and load all the URLs properly.

Comment: I suggest to define the list `List<IWebDriver> driversList = new List<IWebDriver>();` And in the loop: `driversList.Add(new ChromeDriver(chromeService, m_Options))`. In this way you'll be able to interact with each browser outside of the loop.

Comment: And here `pcsInfo.Arguments =  = "--remote-debugging-port=portno --disable-fre --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --user-data-dir=C:\\SeleniumApps\\WebLauncherTool\\bin\\Debug\\ChromeUser\\portno"` you do not inject `int portno` with $. Maybe typo..

Comment: I have identified the issue that when second time I am initializing, the new port is not opened. When I check the port status using `netstat -an` my second port number is not listed there. Is there any piece of code I am missing here? Can you please let me know.

Comment: Does your `GetAvailablePortNumber` method work well? Could you print the port number each time to make sure they are different?

Comment: Yes, every time it is providing different free port numbers.

Comment: @Ask_SO I see you've accepted the answer. Do you still need help? I suggest before run this code add 2 commands invocation: `taskkill /IM "chrome.exe" /F`, `taskkill /IM "chromedriver.exe" /F`. Otherwise I have no ideas.. I've tested your command for launching chrome and it works for me for 3 instances. I able to find all ports with `netstat`.

Comment: I have identified the problem, it is due to `--user-data-dir=' value that I am assigning. If I assign different user data directory path for each URL, then it is working fine.  Not just port number I need to assign entirely different path then only it is working fine.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort.